# Recursion - Buscar en un objeto anidado

Tags: javascript

Implementar la función objContains: debe buscar dentro de un objeto anidado un par {clave: valor}
especifico. Tanto el objeto como el nombre de la propiedad y su valor serán recibidos por parámetro.
En el caso de que encuentre el valor indicado en cualquier nivel del objeto debe devolver true,
de lo contrario, devolver false.

```
var objContains = function(obj, prop, value){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) === true){
      if (obj[prop].includes(value)) return true;
      for (let element of obj[prop]){
        if(objContains(obj,element,value) === true) return true; 
      }     
    }
    return false;
};
```

No logro hacer correr el código, alguien me ayuda?

Comment: "No logro hacer correr el código" <- por? que pasa?

Comment: Esa llamada a includes no tiene mucho sentido, no es un método de Object.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Como es un ejercicio que tienes que resolver, prefiero no dar la respuesta completa de entrada, pero examinemos el ejercicio:

- Tenemos una función `objContains(object, key, value)`
- Un caso base sería devolver `true` si se cumple que

```javascript
if (object[key] === value) {
  return true
}
```

- Otro caso base sería que `object`no sea realmente un objeto:

```javascript
if (typeof object !== 'object') {
  return false;
}
```

- En otro caso, debemos obtener todas las propiedades que tiene ese objeto y recorrerlas para comprobar si esa clave existe. Para eso podemos usar [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Una vez tenemos todas las propiedades, podemos llamar recursivamente sobre todas ellas. Si seguimos sin encontrar lo que buscamos, devolveremos `false`.

**Notas**:

- Hay que tener cuidado de no intentar buscar propiedades en valores que no son objetos, puesto que esto puede causar recursión infinita.
- Este tipo de búsqueda sólo funciona si estamos buscando valores que no son objetos, la búsqueda de objetos sería muy compleja ya que `{} !== {}` (son dos objetos distintos).

Aquí está la solución completa, pero te recomiendo no mirarla de entrada, sino que trates de resolver por tu cuenta antes el problema

```js
const test = {
  prop1: 'A',
  prop2: {
     prop11: 'B'
  },
  prop3: [0, 1, { prop31: 9} ]
};

function objContains(obj, key, value) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }
  if (obj[key] === value) {
    return true;
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (let k of keys) {
    if (objContains(obj[k], key, value)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log([
objContains(test, 'prop1', 'A'), //true
objContains(test, 'prop11', 'B'), //true
objContains(test, 'prop11', 'C'), //false
objContains(test, 'prop2', 'A'), //false
objContains(test, 'prop31', 9), //true
objContains(test, 'prop2', 'A') //false
])
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo, todavía estoy intentando con a info que me pasaste sin ver la respuesta.(igual ya estoy mas orientado.)